# What are the required steps to have a new, fresh and empty SmartGWT project which you build via Maven?

Tags: eclipse, gwt, maven-2, maven-3, smartgwt

I want to start a new **SmartGWT** project in **Eclipse**. I would like to make it buildable via **Maven**. What are the required steps to have a new, fresh and empty **SmartGWT** project which you build via **Maven** and can directly run from **Eclipse** without any hussles?

**PS:**

There are many guides out there but none of them have satisfied my needs so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven uses archetypes for creating new projects with the minimum configuration files and with the standard directory structure.
I quickly googled Smart-GWT Maven Archetype and this seems to be what you're looking for:

http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt-ea/wiki/HowToEclipseGWTMaven

It uses M2Eclipse (integration of Maven in Eclipse, has nothing to do with GWT) so you can run, build, compile, install etc directly from Eclipse.

Comment: actually, I want to run the maven from the command prompt and not from Eclipse. Do you have an idea about what the goals should be in maven pom files ?

Comment: It doesn't matter where you run it from... I use both, whatever is more convenient at the time... I use the goals: compile, test, i18n, generateAsync from the GWT plugin... exploded from the maven-war-plugin.... I think that's all in the pom... when I want to compile only server-side code, I do mvn compile... only client-side, I use the GWT host mode... for both, I have to do mvn clean install... and for running it (be within Eclipse or command line) I do "mvn gwt:run".

Comment: are you sure this link is up to date? I am having tons of problems in downloading m2e.

Comment: Well, you can check the M2E documentation, at:  http://wiki.eclipse.org/Maven_Integration where they say the Eclipse installation URL is: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

Answer (score 1):

Combining the information from @Renato's answer and [maven in 5 minutes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html), the following should help you create a gwt project from command-line.

> mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mygroup -DartifactId=my-gwt-proj
>   -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-googlewebtoolkit2-archetype -DarchetypeGroupId=com.totsp.gwt -DarchetypeRepository=http://gwt-maven.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mavenrepo
>   -DinteractiveMode=false

Thereafter you would want to follow the steps outlined in the [HowTo](http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt-ea/wiki/HowToEclipseGWTMaven) link to make it SmartGWT.

Comment: are you sure this link is up to date? I am having tons of problems in downloading m2e.

Comment: @AdelBoutros.  The link for m2e is out-of-date. m2e is available [here](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/).